# Proper way of utilizing gearman with my php application

Tags: php, gearman

For now I just want to use Gearman for background processing. For example, I need to email a recipient that they have a private message waiting for them once the sender submits their message into the DB. I assume I can run the worker/client and server on my primary server but I have no problems offloading some of the tasks to a different web server.

Anyways, my question is how do I handle multiple "functions?" Let's say I need a job that handles the email portion and a job to handle image manipulation. Can I have multiple functions in the worker? I've followed a couple of examples I found online but each example only shows one function being initialized. Do I have to start up multiple "workers" to handle multiple functions?

Comment: read: "How to properly use German with my PHP application?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have multiple functions in the worker? I've followed a couple of examples I found online but each example only shows one function being initialized.

When you register with the Gearman server, you tell it all the things you can handle.  Check out the [GearmanWorker](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.gearmanworker.php) class and the addFunction method.  (This blindly assumes you're using that particular Gearman extension.  There are others.)